# IO.inspect inside elixir Macros

Tags: elixir

I am new to meta programming. I wrote a small macro that will take fields and match them if they are present in the list.

```
 defmodule some do
   defmacro __using__(_options) do
     quote location: :keep do


  defmacro create(fields) do
    Enum.map(required, fn(field) ->
      quote do
        test "#{unquote(required)} is necessary to create (#{unquote(fields)})" do
          member = Enum.member?(unquote(fields), unquote(field))
          assert true == member
        end
      end
    end)
  end  
end
end
```

I want to use `IO.inspect` to see its execution step by step or load it in the iex to see the output.But i can't figure out how to debug it. because IO.inspect not working inside the macro

Comment: Which part exactly do you want to print? You can add `IO.inspect` before `quote do` to print that AST whenever it's built.

Comment: @Dogbert   I want to print the `fields`. I tried using `IO.inspect`. But it doesn't seem to work anywhere inside macro. it works outside the macro just fine.